# What is "Bluewire General Property Sheet" in Windows shell extensions?

Tags: shell-extensions

Windows 7 is closing to end of support, but I still can't find any information on what is "Bluewire General Property Sheet" shell extension, and do I need it anywhere? It is preinstalled with Windows 7.

Comment: How do you know its installed?

Comment: "It is preinstalled with Windows 7." - No; It actually isn't.

Comment: well, I found it in many places in many installations. Including my machine. Maybe it is a part of some common software, or driver, present in most systems? Try googling it - there will be many listed examples. But no explanation, what it is. I thought about BlueTooth, because of blue, but there is no BT adapter in my system; so it is something else.

Comment: @Moab: ShellExView. I am trying to clean the system, from lags in Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the BWContextHandler.dll with a text editor, it is related to Bluetooth, even if you do not have Bluetooth hardware it is part of the original Windows installation files.

I would not worry about it, leave the entry alone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It gives some certainty.

Comment: Please upvote my answer by clicking the up triangle over the 0, this will help the community use it as a duplicate if the same question is asked by someone else. Thank You.

Comment: can't - stackexchange engine has a flaw: if in your initial post is down-voted by some leftist-socialist wearing pink glasses and not accepting ugly truth, you will be banned from voting and giving valued answers forever, and can not climb back, also because you are banned. So I am limited in options here, sorry. I hope someone else will put a [+] here.